# Unlock content without InAppPurchase external registration on website

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

i'm developing an app that is free if you bought a book (traditional paper book).
Basically i need to lock content for users without a book.
Possible solutions:
1-unlock code inside the book
2-external registration on a website and authentication (username+password) inside the app.

i know that in most cases in app purchase is the solution, but in my case i dont need users to pay inside the app....i only need to check they bought the book.

How to not be rejected from apple?

Thanks

Comment: Option 1 will definitely be rejected by Apple. You could try option 2, but then you risk rejection because your app isn't broadly applicable

Answer (score -1):

You can have a check at the start of the app using a database to see if the [International Standard Book Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) matches the ones for your book (Of course this won't work with second-hand books). If this is not feasible I believe your first option seems the easiest.

Comment: Thanks.....you solution would be ok for me but.....are you sure the app will not be rejected from apple? i read [https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments] in particular 3.1.3(a) ... but i need to be sure